# Greedy for Solving The uncapacitated facility location problem

Tags: python, greedy

**I am trying to solve a Uncapacity facility location Problem but fist i need to apply geedy algoithme to find the min cost, Data should be stored in a txt file but i am using a matrix for now ... Can someone help me? Maybe I am doing something wrong on the Optmization formula ...I am not familiar with this python
Any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance**

```
    import numpy as np
test=[[65, 49, 56, 43, 43, 91, 32, 87],
       [36,  8, 74, 10, 12, 75, 20, 47],
       [36,  8, 74, 10, 12, 75, 20, 47],
       [1, 86, 34, 14, 70, 42, 66, 47],
       [68, 94, 45, 87, 84, 4, 45, 69],
       [87, 36, 75, 35, 93, 39, 1, 0]]
m=np.matrix(test)
facility=[100,500,600,400,700,100,650,850]
vx=np.copy(test)


    print(test) 
for line in test:
    for col in line:
          i=test.index(line)
          j=line.index(col)
          if [col]==[min(line)]:
                test[i][j]=1
                
for line in test:
    for col in line:
          k=test.index(line)
          z=line.index(col)
          if col!=1:
            test[k][z]=0              
print(test)   
print(vx) 

    g=np.sum(test, axis=0)
print(g)
print(facility)
print(g)
d=[]
for i in range(len(g)):
    if(g[i]!=0):
        d.append(facility[i]/g[i])
    else:
        d.append(None)
print(d)  
min1=np.min([x for x in d if x is not None])
print(min1)
pos=d.index(min1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 from pulp import *
 import copy
 import numpy as np
 import numpy.random as rnd
 import math
 import random
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

generate random dictionaries

```
 mydict={}
 transportation_cost={}
 cost={}
 for mo in range(100):
    for ni in range(10):
       mydict[ni]=rnd.randint(1,10)
       cost[ni]=rnd.randint(1,10) 
    transportation_cost[mo]=mydict
    mydict={}
 customers=list(range(100))
 Facility=list(range(10))
```

the greedy def:

```
 def greedy():
initial=np.zeros((len(customers),len(Facility)))
final=np.zeros((len(customers),len(Facility)))
fact_final=np.zeros(len(Facility))
#trouver le min
k=[]
for key1, value1 in transportation_cost.items():
    for key, value in value1.items():
        if value== min(value1.values()):
            initial[key1,key]=1
            k.append([key1,key])   
#sum des min
g=np.sum(initial, axis=0)
#transformer le dictionnaire=> matrice
global original
original=[]
for line in transportation_cost.values():
    val_list = list(line.values())
    original.append(val_list)
#list cout
global cout
cout= list(cost.values())
#greedy algo
stop=[0]
while(any(v==0 for v in stop)):
    l=[]
    nn=[]
    b=[]
    inf=np.sum(initial,axis=0)
    for i in range(len(inf)):
        if inf[i]!=0:
            b.append(cout[i]/inf[i])
        else:
            b.append(0)
    x=min(x for x in b if x!=0)
    j=np.where(b==x)
    J=j[0]
    fact_final[J[0]]=1
    l=np.where(initial[:,J[0]]==1)
    nn=l[0]
    for i in range(len(nn)):
        initial[nn[i],:]=0
        final[nn[i],J[0]]=1
    stop=np.sum(final,axis=1)
#calcule cout
w=np.sum(np.multiply(final,original))
s=np.sum(fact_final*cout)
total=w+s  
return [original,cout,total,final,fact_final]
```

I also added a def that returns the exact/optimal solution:

```
 def optimal():
# Setting the Problem
prob = LpProblem("Uncapacited_Facility_Location_Problem", LpMinimize)
# Defining our Desicion Variables
use_facility = LpVariable.dicts("Use Facility", Facility, 0, 1,range(0,1))
ser_customer = LpVariable.dicts("Service", [(i,j) for i in Facility for j in customers], 0, 1, range(0,1))
# Setting the Objective Function
prob += lpSum(cost[i]*use_facility[i] for i in Facility) + lpSum(transportation_cost[j][i]*ser_customer[(i,j)] for i in Facility for j in customers)
# Costraints
for j in customers:
    prob += lpSum(ser_customer[(i,j)] for i in Facility) == 1 #je croi que le poblem est ici

for j in customers:
    for i in Facility:
        prob += ser_customer[(i,j)] <= use_facility[i]
prob.solve()    
print("Solution Status = ", LpStatus[prob.status])
# Print the solution of Binary Decision Variables
Tolerance = 0.0001
for i in Facility:
    if use_facility[i].varValue > Tolerance:
        print("Estalish Facility at site = ", i)
# Print the solution of Continuous Decision Variables
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)  
# Print Optimal
global h
h=value(prob.objective)
print("Total Cost = ", value(prob.objective))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).